# Choosing a safe /boot mount point for dual booting alongside Windows 10 | Writing /boot mount-point INSIDE Window's existing boot (FAT32) partition

Tags: linux, boot, windows, dual-boot

I have **Windows 10** installed and I want to install Manjaro Linux and use dual boot while keeping my Windows untouched.

Where is the safest location for assigning **/boot** mount point?

I am following [this tutorial](http://linuxbsdos.com/2016/11/07/how-to-dual-boot-manjaro-16-10-windows-10-on-a-computer-with-uefi-firmware/), however I am confused about one section. I do not understand why they choose to **define a /boot/efi point inside** the already-existing **FAT32 Windows boot partition** (first one in the partition table).

1. Does the above practice make any sense?
2. **Is it safe to define a new /boot/efi point on the already-existing Windows-created boot point?** Will this not tamper with Windows booting process?
3. **Why not** simply create a whole **new partition** for `/boot/efi`?

Answer (score 0):

The EFI System Partition is not the "Windows boot partition". It is a special partition recognized by the UEFI firmware that is shared by all installed operating systems. The ESP is from where the firware loads EFI programs to be run at boot. There can be only one ESP on the disk, and it is identified by a special UUID.

You can think of the ESP as a vastly enlarged boot sector, which does not get overwritten every time a new operating system is installed. Instead it has room for several boot loaders and other programs, and which program is loaded at boot is determined by variables stored in non-volatile memory on the motherboard.